# How to resize and center image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

I would like to set not square image to square and use for this square center of image. How to done it with paperclip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will take an image, crop in the center of the image at 500x500, then throw everything else away, then resize that new image back down to 100x100. It's used for generating square thumbnails, but you can adjust this for your needs.

```
has_attached_file :image,  
  :styles => { :thumb => "" },
  :convert_options => { 
    :thumb => "-gravity Center -crop 500x500+0+0 +repage -resize 100x100^", 
  :default_style => :thumb
```